# Manipulate elements of an array by different factors without creating variables for each element

Tags: arrays, ruby, sum

I want to manipulate the elements of an array by different factors and then sum them.

Is there a more elegant way of writing this code:

```
test = '02:30:09:00'

test2 = test.split(':')

t1 = test2[0].to_i * 3600
t2 = test2[1].to_i * 60
t3 = test2[2].to_i
t4 = test2[3].to_i

dur =  t1 + t2 + t3 + t4

p "#{dur} seconds"
```

I was wondering if there was a way of doing this without creating a variable for each element of the array as I have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To improve readability, consider about extract method like:

```
def seconds_amount(hours, minutes, seconds, cents)
  hours.to_i * 3600 + minutes.to_i * 60 + seconds.to_i + cents.to_f / 100
end

test = '02:30:09:00'
test2 = test.split(':')
puts seconds_amount(*test2)
  # => 9009
```

New variables in Ruby are not a big problem usually - it does not allocate additional memory, variables are just a pointers to the same objects.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm very new to ruby and this method is exactly what I was looking for, very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Well, don't create the variables then

```
dur = test2[0].to_i * 3600 + test2[1].to_i * 60 + ...
```

Although, I find that extracting variables with speaking names usually improves readability. The keyword is: "speaking names". Compare:

```
hours_in_secs = time_parts[0].to_i * 3600
minutes_in_secs = time_parts[1].to_i * 60
seconds = time_parts[2].to_i

duration_in_seconds = hours_in_secs + minutes_in_secs + seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'02:30:09:00'.split(":").zip([3600, 60, 1, 1])
.inject(0){|dur, (s, factor)| dur + s.to_i * factor}
# => 9009
```

Comment: Splitting expressions in several lines with dot starting the line is not IRB-friendly :)

Answer (score 0):

I just try some lambda.

```
test = '02:30:09:00'

dur = test.split(':').zip([3600, 60, 1, 1]).map(&->(s, i){ s.to_i * i }).inject(:+)

p "#{dur} seconds"
# => "9009 seconds"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'time'

str = '02:30:09:12'

fmt = "%H:%M:%S:%L"
seconds = DateTime.strptime(str << '0', fmt).to_time -
          DateTime.strptime("00:00:00:000", fmt).to_time
  #=> 9009.12
```

- I presume the last two characters of the string (`"12"`, which I changed from `"00"` to make it more interesting) are hundredths of a second. `'02:30:09:12' << '0' #=> "02:30:09:120"` converts `12` hundredths of a second to `120` milliseconds.
- See the class method [DateTime::strptime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime) and, for a key to the format string used by `strptime`, the instance method [DateTime#strtime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime).
- `"%L"` in the format string is for (zero-padded) milliseconds.
- `DateTime.strptime(str << '0', fmt).to_time` equals the number of seconds since the epoch.
- `DateTime.strptime("00:00:00:000", fmt).to_time` equals the number of seconds between the epoch and the previous midnight. The difference between the two `Time` values therefore equals the numbers of seconds elapsed since the previous midnight.